# In NextJS 13, how to get the variable params in an API route?

Tags: next.js13

I’m trying to access [id] from `/api/v1/[id]/start` in my nextjs project:

```
// in /api/v1/[id]/start/route.ts
export async function GET(req: Request) {
  console.log("GET", req); // <== console log the "id" here
}
```

I am using the newest app router.
How is this done? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Ah! Found it in the docs: https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/file-conventions/route#context-optional

So there is an optional second param being passed "context" which holds the value:

```
export async function GET(req: Request, context: { params: { id: string } }) {
  console.log("GET", context.params.id);
}
```

Thank you!